# Xamarin Forms HttpClient PostAsync always throw NSMallocException

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, httpclient

We are building a mobile app for iOS and Android using Xamarin Forms 5 and using Visual Studio 2022. When we make a Post request to any api, both our own as external api's we are always returned:

`Xamarin.PreBuilt.iOS[3728:2199180] Xamarin.iOS: Received unhandled ObjectiveC exception: NSMallocException Failed to grow buffer`

GET request work fine. I have searched Google and StackOverflow but can not find any help. I have tried to increase the HttpClient.MaxResponseContentBufferSize without any difference.

The app for now is very simple, one page with a button to test. Code behind is as followed:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://ptsv2.com/");

            string jsonData = @"{}";

            var content = new StringContent(jsonData, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync("/t/l4x2e-1637576441/post", content);

            var result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        }
    }
```

This fails on iOS linked device, but for Android Simulator it works. Is there anything I need to change for iOS?

**Update**

The code works on multiple machines except mine, trying to figure out what setting this could be, any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you see a stack dump after that exception in VS Output pane? If so, please add the stack dump to your question. Google shows this sometimes been an issue for various libraries on ios. Only specific cause I see is running out of memory. google `Received unhandled Objective C exception: NSMallocException Failed to grow buffer`

Comment: Try doing the equivalent request in PostMan. That sometimes gives a more informative response. Not related to this error specifically, but sometimes adding a `/` at end avoids a redirect. (redirect can lose body json content) `"/t/l4x2e-1637576441/post/"`

Comment: Your code looks totally correct , and I test with `VS 2022 , Xamarin.Forms 5 , iPhone12 simulator , iOS 15.0` , it works fine without any error .

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve, no stack dump in the Output pane except the error it self.

Comment: @ColeX-MSFT, thanks for testing, any clue what settings could effect this? I tested on multiple iPhones.

Comment: This is a memory out error , what is the your iPhone  spec?  If it is too old(e,g iPhone5) , it could be raise the error because it has less ram amount , try this on a newer iPhone .

Comment: I tried this both on an iPhone 12 and iPhone 7 with iOS 15.0.2

Comment: I tested it on an iPhone XR and it doesn't work, also on iPhone 6. I changed Visual Studio back to 2019 version and everything worked on both phones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had exactly the same problem, and have logged a ticket with Microsoft on the VS feedback forums. And then today I found a simple work-around. At least I assume it's a work-around and not a solution. Where I had

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient()
```

I instead do this:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
```

And bingo, it now works.

Comment: Worked for me as well. Could you keep this answer updated if Microsoft provides more information?

Comment: Will do. It's been 'Under investigation' with Microsoft since 8 Dec 2021.